# $y = (x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}) - 6(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}) + 3(x + \frac{1}{x})$ find min value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, optimization, maxima-minima, substitution

> $y = (x^3 + \frac{1}{x^3}) - 6(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}) + 3(x + \frac{1}{x})$ find min value

$t = x + \frac{1}{x}$

$y = t^3 -6t^2 + 12$

critical point when $t = 4, x = 2 \pm \sqrt3 $

it's hard to evaluate the value of $f(2 - \sqrt3) $ manually

is there a way to evaluate it in easy way? (not allowed using calculator)

Comment: $1/(2-\sqrt3)=2+\sqrt3; (2+\sqrt3)^2=7+4\sqrt3;  1/(2-\sqrt3)^2=7-4\sqrt3$

Comment: Put $t=4$ into the other equation instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal value does not exist. Try $x\rightarrow0^-.$

For $x>0$ we can use AM-GM.

Indeed, let $x+\frac{1}{x}=2u$.

Thus, $u\geq1$ and
$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}-6\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=$$
$$=8u^3-6u-6(4u^2-2)+6u=8u^3-24u^2+12=$$
$$=4\left(2u^3-6u^2+3\right)=4\left(2u^3+8-6u^2-5\right)\geq4\left(3\sqrt[3]{(u^3)^2\cdot8}-6u^2-5\right)=-20.$$
The equality occurs for $u=2$, which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Can you please clarify this $$=8u^3-6u-6(4u^2-2)+6u=8u^3-24u^2+12=$$
$$=4\left(2u^3-6u^2+3\right)=8\left(2u^3+8-6u^2-5\right)\geq8\left(3\sqrt[3]{(u^3)^2\cdot8}-6u^2-5\right)=-20.$$

Comment: @Lifeforbetter I used AM-GM for three positive numbers: $a+b+c\geq3\sqrt[3]{abc},$ where $a=b=u^3$ and $c=8.$

Comment: why set x+1/x as 2u? is there simpler way to solve it?

Comment: It's a substitution only. I think it's a simplest way to find a minimal value. I fixed a typo